# How does distribution mechanism works when Kafka runs locally?

Tags: apache-kafka

How does distribution mechanism works when Kafka runs locally? Please tell the disadvantages too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only run one broker locally, you have a single point of failure and no processing is truly distributed

If you have multiple brokers on the same machine, and you mount different volumes for each broker process logs, you'd end up with distributed storage + fault tolerance, but still no distributed processing

In either case, you can create as many topics as you want with many partitions, but you can only set the replication factor of the topics to be the number of active brokers

Multiple consumer processes are also able to run fine on a single machine, but you'd get more throughput by separating brokers and consumers across several physical machines (more cpu available, and different network interfaces)

Comment: Okay, so there is a limitation in how much data can be dumped by the producer right, even though we add many brokers.

Comment: The limit is your disk space

Comment: Basically Kafka brokers are the different servers right, but in local machine there can only be one server,so can we say multiple brokers in the same machine means multiple process running in a machine?